# Can we install ubuntu 12.04 from downloaded iso file using wubi installer?

Tags: installation

When I try to install ubuntu 12.04.2 64 bit using wubi installer. It starts to download the file instead of using already downloaded iso file "ubuntu-12.04.2-desktop-amd64". How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and the answer is given on https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide:

> [**How do I install Wubi on a machine with no Internet connection?**](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide)
>
> Wubi also works with physical Ubuntu Desktop Live CDs. Wubi.exe is available in the root folder of the CD.
>
> If you do not have a CD, try to find a computer with Internet access, and download both Wubi.exe and the required Desktop ISO from the same location (the release has to match):

```
For 12.10 use http://releases.ubuntu.com/quantal/
For 12.04 use http://releases.ubuntu.com/precise/
For 11.10 use http://releases.ubuntu.com/oneiric/
For 10.04 use http://releases.ubuntu.com/lucid/
```

> Copy both files into the same folder on the machine with no Internet access and run the Wubi executable.

---

So 2 things you need to do:

- download the ISO matching the wubi version;
- put both into the same directory.